# main program while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a little Python program that uses keyboard input to run certain commands.

I setup everything in one main program loop but now I'm wondering, do I even need a main loop?

Here is what I mean:

```
mainProgramLoop = 1   
while mainProgramLoop == 1:

    print ("\nType in the command. ")

    keyBoardInput= input("command:")

    if keyBoardInput == "a":
       #do this
    elif keyBoardInput == "b":
       #do this
```

Do I actually need that while loop?

Thanks!

Comment: well, you need it if you want more than one command w/o rerunning the code

Comment: You're the only one who knows if you need it. Does it still work correctly if you remove it? If yes, then you don't need it.

Comment: Why do you need the variable mainProgramLoop I would write while 1

Comment: `while True:` would be neater than `mainProgramLoop = 1; while mainProgramLoop == 1:`; then you just `break`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you do not need a main loop if you use the `cmd.Cmd` class included with Python:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import cmd

class App(cmd.Cmd):

    prompt = 'Type in a command: '

    def do_a(self, arg):
        print('I am doing whatever action "a" is.')

    def do_b(self, arg):
        print('I am doing whatever action "b" is.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    App().cmdloop()
```

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html) for the `cmd` module includes an example near the bottom to help get you started.

Comment: Finally, it is a joy to reach 5,000 on SO.

Comment: Birthdays and reputation get less spectacular as life goes on. Was 10,000 all that special? It seems to have been forgotten by now.